# chrome not showing background image in parent div tag

Tags: html, css

I have one parent div tag containing two child div tags and i want to use a image as background.
The css style of parent div tag is:

```css
#maindiv
{
    width:55%;
    background-image:url(F:/sem5/web tech/13sand.jpg);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the body is:

```
<body background="National Geographic Wallpapers 022.jpg" >
<center >
<div id="maindiv"  >
        <h2 style="background-color:#191970;font-family:Verdena;color:white;height:91px;font-size:80px;">Gagandeep Kaur</h2>

        <div style="float:left;width:37%;">
                <table border="0">
                <tr><a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:28px" href="javascript:filldata('ginfo');" >General Information</a><br/><tr>
                <tr><div id="ginfo"></div></tr>
                <tr><a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:28px" href="javascript:filldata('ainfo');" >Academic Information</a><br/></tr>
                <tr><div id="ainfo"></div></tr>
                <tr><a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:28px" href="javascript:filldata('h');" >Hobbies</a><br/></tr>
                <tr><div id="h"></div></tr>
                <tr><a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:28px" href="javascript:filldata('aim');" >Aim</a></tr>
                <tr><div id="aim"></div></tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            <div style="float:right;width:63%;">
                <img src="2011-08-04 18.31.38_1.jpg" align="right" width="300px" height="500px">
                </div>
    </div>

</center>
</body>
```

This code is showing the background in IE but not in chrome.
Where and what is the problem??

Comment: **background-image:url(F:/sem5/web tech/13sand.jpg);**
try change it to 
**background-image:url("F:/sem5/web tech/13sand.jpg");**
and try not to use spaces in folder's name

Comment: You shouldn't use spaces in your file names or directory names - that's very bad practice. Also you are referencing the background image from your 'F' drive. I'll assume this site won't be going live on the internet like that as obviously that won't work.

Comment: okay..i will not use the spaces..and no the site is not going live on internet..i was just trying to do these things on my own as i am new to html and css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting quotes around the image's url?

```
#maindiv
{
    width:55%;
    background-image:url('F:/sem5/web tech/13sand.jpg');
    overflow:hidden;
}
```